# Trying to retrieve a random gif from my mongoose database but the ejs file is stating the 'img' is undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I'm making an ejs app where it returns a randomized gif from a database. I have a page that successfully confirms you uploaded a gif (images page.ejs) but in my home.ejs file where it renders from the /random path I get an error where it can't find the property of 'img' even though it's in my schema. Attached is a link to the GitHub page of a zip file of what I have so far. [Link](https://github.com/shuchattc/gifPractice)

```
`app. get('/random', async (req, res) =>{
    const findGif = await gifFinder();
    res.render('home', {findGif})
});


const gifFinder = async (req, res) => {
    const foundGif = imgModel.count().exec(function (err, count) {

        // Get a random entry
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count)
  
        // Again query all users but only fetch one offset by our random #
       imgModel.findOne().skip(random).exec(
          function (err, result) {
            // Tada! random user
           // console.log(result) 
        
          })
    
      });
      //return the found gif
      return foundGif;
};`
```

Answer (score 0):

`findOne` already returns a random element from the collection:

```
app.get('/random', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const findGif = await imgModel.findOne();
    res.render('home', { findGif });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I realized that after posting like an idiot thank you though appreciate it.